# Por que sujeito é chamado de “sujeito”?

Tags: etimologia

O agente de uma ação é chamado sujeito, mas geralmente algo sujeito é algo que é submetido por outra coisa, não algo que submete. Então, por que o agente de uma ação é chamado sujeito?

Comment: Muito confusão na sua pergunta. O sujeito é o objeto do agente??

Comment: Chama-se *sujeito*, literalmente "aquilo que jaz embaixo" (subiectum, [ὑποκείμενον](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypokeimenon)), porque é sobre quem a afirmação é feita. No caso da voz ativa a sua dúvida é pertinente, como em "o gato comeu o rato", o gato é o sujeito, porque minha afirmação se refere a ele, e é o agente da ação, ou seja, não foi "sujeitado" a ela (daí provavelmente sua dúvida). Mas na voz passiva, "o rato foi comido pelo gato", o rato é o sujeito (minha afirmação se refere a ele), mesmo que ele não seja o *agente* da ação.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Teu comentário é uma ótima resposta, não hesite em postar como tal!